# How do I provide the setting menu on user basis in SharePoint default settings menu?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want the particular settings option on the basis of logged in User. How should I able to achieve this ?

We see the setting action menu at right corner.
I want to show the particular/few menu for visitors and all menu for administrator only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific ? Do you want to add a new link, under the COG icon in the upper right corner, that is only shown for specific users ?

Comment: No i don't want to add new link I am able to do this by using element.xml file. I want specific options for specific user